# Two objects collide, one should disappear without affecting the other's position

Tags: lua, sdk, coronasdk, collision

When object1 collides with object2, I want object2 to disappear without affecting the position or velocity of object1. Object1 is dynamic and object2 is static. So it would be like a bonus object hitting my main object and the bonus object should disappear without affecting anything.

Here is my code for the collision function:

```
local function onCollision( self,event )
        --if my object hits a bonus object
        if(event.object2.name == "bonus")then
            --self:setLinearVelocity(0,horizontal)
            --I have tried the above method but every so often I receive an error
            event.object2:removeSelf()
            score = score*2
            scoreText.text = score --sets the new score
            Runtime:removeEventListener("enterFrame", event.object2)    
        else                
            composer.gotoScene( "restart"  )   
            Runtime:removeEventListener("touch", onObjectTouch)    
        end
    end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

UPDATE:

Try setting your bonus objects as sensors, either in this area, or when you initialize them.

```
    event.object2.isSensor = true
```

OR

```
    object2.isSensor = true
```

This should allow Physics & Collision Detection on object2 without any effect on other objects.

Comment: This doesn't really answer the question

Comment: Yes the object2 is disappearing however it is knocking object1 off course upon collision which is the problem

Comment: `object2.isSensor = true` would be most useful if applied when creating the object. If you apply it during the collision check, it might not take effect until after the collision has been detected, and it has already affected object1